# PHP - Compare multidimensional sub-arrays to each other and merge on similarity threshold

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, compare, levenshtein-distance

### Introduction - This question has been updated the 27th May 2018:

I have 1 **PHP** multidimensional-array, containing 6 sub-arrays, each containing 20 sub-sub-arrays, which in turn, each contain 2 sub-sub-arrays, one being a string (header), the other being an unspecified number of keywords (keywords).

I am looking to compare each of the 120 sub-sub-arrays to the 100 other sub-sub-arrays contained in the remainint 5 sub-arrays. So that *sub-sub-array**1*** in *sub-array**1*** is compared to *sub-array**1*** to and including *sub-array**20*** in *sub-array**2*** to and including *sub-array**6***, and so forth.

If enough ***keywords*** in two sub-sub-arrays are deemed identical and ***headers*** are as well, both using Levenshtein distance, the sub-sub-arrays will be merged.

---

### Example script

I have written a script doing exactly this, but for two separate arrays to demonstrate my goal:

```
<?php
// Variable deciding maximum Levenshtein distance between two words. Can be changed to lower / increase threshhold for whether two keywords are deemed identical.
$lev_point_value = 3;

// Variable deciding minimum amount of identical (passed the $lev_point_value variable) keywords needed to merge arrays. Can be changed to lower / increase threshhold for how many keywords two arrays must have in common to be merged.
$merge_tag_value = 4;

// Variable deciding minimum Levenshtein distance between two headers needed to merge arrays. Can be changed to lower / increase threshhold for whether two titles are deemed identical.
$merge_head_value = 22;

// Array1 - A story about a monkey, includes at header and keywords.
$array1 = array (
        "header" => "This is a story about a monkey.",
        'keywords' => array( "Trees", "Monkey", "Flying", "Drink", "Vacation", "Coconut", "Big", "Bonobo", "Climbing"
    ));

// Array1 - Another, but slightly different story about a monkey, includes at header and keywords.
$array2 = array (
        "header" => "This is another, but different story, about a monkey.",
        'keywords' => array( "Monkey", "Big", "Trees", "Bonobo", "Fun", "Dance", "Cow", "Coconuts"
    ));

// Function comparing keywords between two arrays. Uses levenshtein distance lesser than $lev_point_value. Each pass increases $merged_tag, which is then returned.
function sim_tag_index($array1, $array2, $lev_point_value) {
    $merged_tag = 0;
    foreach ($array1['keywords'] as $item1){
        foreach ($array2["keywords"] as $item2){
            if (levenshtein($item1, $item2) <= $lev_point_value) {
            $merged_tag++;
            };
         }
    };
    return $merged_tag;
}

// Function comparing headers between two arrays using levenshtein distance, which is then returned as $merged_head.
function sim_header_index($array1, $array2) {
    $merged_head = (levenshtein($array1['header'], $array2['header']));
    return $merged_head;
}

// Function running sim_tag_index against $merge_tag_value, if it passes, then running sim_tag_index against $merge_head_value, if this passes aswell, merge arrays.
function merge_on_sim($array1, $array2, $merge_tag_value, $merge_head_value, $lev_point_value) {
    $group = array();
    if (sim_tag_index($array1, $array2, $lev_point_value) >= $merge_tag_value) {
        if (sim_header_index($array1, $array2) >= $merge_head_value) {
            $group = (array_unique(array_merge($array1["keywords"],$array2["keywords"])));
        }
    }
    return $group;
}

// Printing function merge_on_sim.
print_r (merge_on_sim($array1, $array2, $merge_tag_value, $merge_head_value, $lev_point_value));
?>
```

---

### Question:

How can I expand or rewrite my script to go through multiple sub-sub-arrays, comparing them to all other sub-sub-arrays, found in other sub-arrays, and then merge sub-sub-arrays that are deemed identical enough?

---

### Multidimensional Array Structure

```
$array = array (
    // Sub-array 1
    array (
        // Story 'Monkey 1' - Has identical sub-sub-arrays 'Monkey 2' and 'Monkey 3' and will be merged with them.
        array (
            "header" => "This is a story about a monkey.",
            'keywords' => array( "Trees", "Monkey", "Flying", "Drink", "Vacation", "Coconut", "Big", "Bonobo", "Climbing")
        ),
        // Story 'Cat 1' - Has identical sub-sub-array 'Cat 2' and will be merged with it.
        array (
            "header" => "Here's a catarific story about a cat",
            'keywords' => array( "meauw", "raaaw", "kitty", "growup", "Fun", "claws", "fish", "salmon")
        )
    ),
    // Sub-array 2
    array ( 
        // Story 'Monkey 2' - Has identical sub-sub-arrays 'Monkey 1' and 'Monkey 3' and will be merged with them.
        array (
            "header" => "This is another, but different story, about a monkey.",
            'keywords' => array( "Monkey", "Big", "Trees", "Bonobo", "Fun", "Dance", "Cow", "Coconuts")
        ),
        // Story 'Cat 2' - Has identical sub-sub-array 'Cat 1' and will be merged with it.
        array (
            "header" => "Here's a different story about a cat",
            'keywords' => array( "meauwe", "ball", "cat", "kitten", "claws", "sleep", "fish", "purr")
        )
    ),
    // Sub-array 3
    array ( 
        // Story 'Monkey 3' - Has identical sub-sub-arrays 'Monkey 1' and 'Monkey 2' and will be merged with them.
        array (
            "header" => "This is a third story about a monkey.",
            'keywords' => array( "Jungle", "tree", "monkey", "Bonobo", "Fun", "Dance", "climbing", "Coconut", "pretty")
        ),
        // Story 'Fireman 1' - Has no identical sub-sub-arrays and will not be merged.
        array (
            "header" => "This is a story about a fireman",
            'keywords' => array( "fire", "explosion", "burning", "rescue", "happy", "help", "water", "car")
        )
    )
);
```

---

### Wanted Multidimensional Array

```
$array = array (
    // Story 'Monkey 1', 'Monkey 2' and 'Monkey 3' merged.
    array (
        "header" => array( "This is a story about a monkey.", "This is another, but different story, about a monkey.", "This is a third story about a monkey."),
        'keywords' => array( "Trees", "Monkey", "Flying", "Drink", "Vacation", "Coconut", "Big", "Bonobo", "Climbing", "Fun", "Dance", "Cow", "Coconuts", "Jungle", "tree", "pretty")
    ),
    // Story 'Cat 1' and 'Cat 2' merged.
    array (
        "header" => array( "Here's a catarific story about a cat", "Here's a different story about a cat"),
        'keywords' => array( "meauw", "raaaw", "kitty", "growup", "Fun", "claws", "fish", "salmon", "ball", "cat", "kitten", "sleep", "fish", "purr")
    )
);
```

Comment: please select your language and add what you have tried and have a look here, too: [mcve]

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have specified that my arrays are PHP, but that I can work in other languages, which I have specified as well. Should I try to make this more clear? Also, I am starting from rock bottom on this problem, I have no idea how to do this and am looking for help how to best tackle this - I therefor sadly have no code to reconstruct any code-problems, other than my array structure. But thank you for the link, I will use it next time it's applicable.

Comment: please add a wanted result of the comparing

Comment: Meta advice: when posting, try to avoid (a) noting how long you have been stuck, as that will not affect the answers, nor help prioritise your question; (b) add commentary on your own levels of learning, since the question and its answers are for a wide audience; (c) add thanks and other chatty material, since we prefer a technical standard of writing here, (d) add general requests for hints and tips, since that's rather vague, and specific/focussed questions are preferred.

Comment: At what threshold should the arrays be merged? How many similar words must there be?

Comment: I prefer these 'settings' to be stored in variables and as such, easily changeable, as seen in my example script; $lev_point_value, $merge_tag_value and $merge_head_value. For demonstration purpose, in an answer, the supplied array would function well with a levenshtein value of 2 for words, 15 for headers and 4 for number of similar words - but again, the actual values are unimportant.

Comment: @Nenn Ok, Then I guessed correct :-) I posted an answer that is without levenshtein but with preg_grep. You can tweek slightly with preg_grep to match "balls" with "ball"  if you need it, but it's not as flexible as levenshtein. Good and bad...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give it a go!

I use preg_grep to find items that are the same in the other subarrays. Then I use count to see how many matching keywords there is.
And that is where the threshold is. Currently I set it to `2`, that means two matching keywords is a match.

```
//flatten array to make it simpler
$new =[];
foreach($array as $subarr){
    $new = array_merge($new, $subarr);
}

$threshold = 2;
$merged=[];
foreach($new as $key => $story){
    // create regex pattern to find similar items
    $words = "/" . implode("|", $story["keywords"]) . "/i";
    foreach($new as $key2 => $story2){
        // only loop new items and items that has not been merged already
        if($key != $key2 && $key2 > $key && !in_array($key2, $merged)){
            // If the count of words from preg_grep is above threshold it's mergable
            if(count(preg_grep($words, $story2["keywords"])) > $threshold){
                // debug
                //echo $key . " " . $key2 . "\n";
                //echo $story["header"] . " = " . $story2["header"] ."\n\n";

                // if the item does not exist create it first to remove notices
                if(!isset($res[$key])) $res[$key] = ["header" => [], "keywords" =>[]];

                // add headers
                $res[$key]["header"][] = $story["header"];
                $res[$key]["header"][] = $story2["header"];

                // only keep unique 
                $res[$key]["header"] = array_unique($res[$key]["header"]);

                // add keywords and remove duplicates
                $res[$key]["keywords"] = array_merge($res[$key]["keywords"], $story["keywords"], $story2["keywords"]);
                $res[$key]["keywords"] = array_unique($res[$key]["keywords"]);

                // add key2 to merged so that we don't merge this again.
                $merged[] = $key2;
            }
        }
    }
}

var_dump($res);
```

https://3v4l.org/6cKRq

Output is as your "wanted" in question.

Comment: Thank you for your fantastic answer. It is exactly what I need, except for the fact that I sadly need the finetuning of levenshtein, that preg_grep doesn't provide. Would it be possible to rewrite your answer, substituting preg_grep for levenshtein for the bounty? It would completely solve my problem.

Comment: It's possible. But is it due to plural of words as I wrote in comments to question? That can be handled in preg_grep too. The times I have used levenhstein it is very loose when comparing keywords. "Brick", " wall" is very close to "trick", "ball" but the context is completely different. One is possibly about football and one is about building a house. Preg_grep would not match these.

Comment: I can see what you mean, but that is surely why levenshtein have parameters for insertion, replacement and deletion cost, is it not? Preg_grep seems too strict as it is now, and will not identify 'meauw' and 'meauwe' as being identical and therefore not merge the two cat stories, on a threshold of 3. My keywords will often include 2 words, essentially the same, but spelled slightly differently. Could an addition of levenshtein, within the preg_grep foreach, comparing the two words, maybe solve this or would you recommend differently?

Comment: @Nenn I see what you mean. I will give it a try when I have time. Perhaps now if my son stays calm for a moment.

Comment: Don't worry, I have included the levenshtein distance into your script myself, arguably without the preg_grep, as it was causing me trouble. You can find the script here https://3v4l.org/8pNAo and you're welcome to rewrite it if you see any possible problems and add that to your answer. Nonetheless, I will be choosing your answer as the bounty winner tomorrow, thank you for your help!

Comment: @Nenn LOL Now that I see your code that is pretty much identical to the code I have written so far. https://3v4l.org/TOJ92 Note I only made it to if $match >= 3 then I saw your comment. I advice you not to give away the bounty yet. It's your choise, but I think it's better to wait and see if something better comes up. Giving it away early might "scare away" people from trying

Comment: Hah, that is indeed similar and thank you for the advice, I will take that to heart.

Comment: Did you want some levenshtein (or something else) to match headers?

Comment: Yes, actually I do. Checking for levenshtein similarity on headers after, or even before keyword check, obviously with a less strict value, but that's for testing later.

Comment: Levenhstein again? I think this code is going to be really really slow. Levenhstein requires two nesting loops and that will make it slow. The logic will be the same just comparing then headers instead of keywords. I will try to think of a different solution that may be quicker.

Comment: Take this as an not complete code, but more as a guideline. I have removed the keyword matching part and just focus on the title. Note the change in the second foreach where I use array_splice, that way I don't need to check if key is larger than key. I create an associative array with the letters, my hope is that you can match first letter against other words first letter. See the new array structure. I use array_intersect to to only check first letters available in both arrays. I don't think testing this on the examples will get a good result as they are all "a story about".

Comment: But if you try it on the real array it may be quicker than doing every word against every word. Possibly it can work on the keywords too? https://3v4l.org/4h7Mr

Comment: Thank you for the link. That's a very interesting solution and as I am quite the beginner at PHP, I will study it intensely. The script will, however, run offline, with arrays of manageable size, so speed isn't an issue as such - not for this prototype anyway. I created https://3v4l.org/jPBht, based on your previous script a check for both header and keywords using similar_text, which after a few tests, proved most accurate with my real life data. You've been a fantastic help, I have learned a lot and the bounty is rightfully yours, cheers!

Comment: Thank you very much! It has been a fun challenge. I enjoy array matching/rebuilding questions that is more than the average question. If speed is not an issue then I understand that you can nest loops, just remember that if your data grows and you run it again then it might become an issue. I had an Excel sheet at work that did some crazy calculations through formulas (5 rows in formula bar). In the begining it was all good, but as the data size increased it took about five hours to finnish.